# Header size changes when switching between languages in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am currently working on a website, [urbano2020.com/Drupal](http://urbano2020.com/Drupal).

The header size is different between the Spanish and English translation. You can check it out and see what I mean...

I have tried disabling the 'Mi Cuenta' link, but this had no effect.

Does anyone have any idea what could have caused this or how to fix this so that the header stays the same size?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of the words and sentences are pushing content around.

For example in the header in the English version it says "The local urgency of the unreached in 20 cities by 2020" this length keeps everything formatted because divs aren't being pushed under each other. In the Spanish version that text is longer so the rest of the content in the header gets pushed under it expanding the header.

My fix: add word wrapping to the text that pushes the rest of the content by placing it in a div with a fixed width value.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, and how would you recommend I do that ? @TheProWolfPcGames ,  Sorry, I'm a bit new to Drupal.

Comment: In the html file surround the text with <div style='width: 100px;'> your text here </div> you can change the 100 to what ever works that is the length in pixels of the div.